# UTF-8 Not working in the JQuery plugin Jeditable

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jeditable

I have added a meta tag like this,

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

to my page. I have made sure that the MySQL table column in question is "utf8_unicode_ci" and I added a charset= to my jquery call as in

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jeditable.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

But a slash (/) for example still comes out as '%2F'.
Anyone see why MySQL isn't storing it as a '/' slash and why my web page isn't displaying it as a '/'?

Comment: We need more info. It's not enough to add meta tags, you need to SAVE the content using utf-8.

Comment: Maybe: http://php.net/manual/es/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "SAVE the content using utf-8". Can you give me an example?